# join equal or max

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max

I want to join two tables by 'EmployeeId' and 'CalendarMonthId', but problem is that I want to connect record with the bigest CalednarMonthId if not exist equal. I use Azure Synapse SQL pool.
Example data and code

```
create table emp_contr (
    EmployeeId int,
    CalendarMonthId int,
    IsDeleted int
    --login varchar(20) 
)

create table contr (
    ContractId int,
    EmployeeId int,
    CalendarMonthId int,
    value int
)

insert into emp_contr values (1, 202201, 0)
insert into emp_contr values (1, 202202, 0)
insert into emp_contr values (1, 202205, 0)
insert into emp_contr values (1, 202206, 0)
insert into emp_contr values (2, 202202, 0)
insert into emp_contr values (2, 202203, 0)

insert into contr values (1, 1, 202201, 5)
insert into contr values (2, 1, 202202, 2)
insert into contr values (40, 2, 202202, 2)
insert into contr values (50, 2, 202203, 0)
```

Base on this data I have problem with connect table: emp_contr, row: EmployeeId:1, CalendarMonthId:202205 with row from table contr from the same user and maximum CalendarMonthId:202202. I have query like this, but it doesn't work

```
select * 
from emp_contr ec
join contr c
    on ec.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
    and (ec.CalendarMonthId = c.CalendarMonthId or ec.CalendarMonthId > max(c.CalendarMonthId))
order by ec.EmployeeId
```

I expect result like this:

| EmployeeId | Emp_Contr_CalendarMonthId | Contr_CalendarMonthId | Value | ContractId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202206 | 202202 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 202205 | 202202 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 202202 | 202202 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 202201 | 202201 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 202203 | 202203 | 0 | 50 |
| 2 | 202202 | 202202 | 2 | 40 |

I don't know what I should do. Maybe should I add row in temporary table based on contr table with the same values like bigest one but different CalendarMonthId

Comment: Please specify what database this is.

Comment: what you need in output please describe here.

Comment: @kometen MS SQL/ Azure Synapse SQL pool

Comment: Thank you @l_obr. Please update your question to include the relevant database.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya - I added expectet result to my Question.

Comment: I assume `202202`  in row 4, col 3 of the results should be `202201`?

Comment: @JensSchauder - sorry my mistake ;) it should be 202201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

```sql
select ec.EmployeeId, ec.CalendarMonthId Emp_Contr_CalendarMonthId, 
  coalesce(c.CalendarMonthId,c2.CalendarMonthId) Contr_CalendarMonthId, 
  coalesce(c.value,c2.value) value, 
  coalesce(c.ContractId,c2.ContractId) ContractId,
-- additional columns for debugging
  c.CalendarMonthId, c.value, c.ContractId, 
  c2.CalendarMonthId, c2.value, c2.ContractId 
from emp_contr ec
left join contr c
on ec.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
and ec.CalendarMonthId = c.CalendarMonthId
join (
  select * 
  from (
    select EmployeeId,
         CalendarMonthId, 
         value, 
         ContractId,
         row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by CalendarMonthId desc) rn
    from contr
  ) x 
  where rn = 1
) c2 on ec.EmployeeId = c2.EmployeeId
order by ec.EmployeeId, ec.CalendarMonthId desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/051de/18)

The `coalesce` assumes all relevant columns are `NOT NULL`. If this is not the case you'll have to replace them with CASE-expressions in which you check if `c.CalendarMonthId is null`.

### Explanation

The statement joins `contr` twice.

First using an outer join to obtain the matching results when present, without loosing rows without a match.

The second join is an inner join.
This assumes there is at least one `contr` row per `emp_contr`
The join does join an inline view which
uses the window function `row_number()` to filter only the last row per employee when ordered by `CalendarMonthId`

The last step is to combine the results, and pick the one from the first join if present and the one from the second join if not.